# Change the icon of a file and lock it

Tags: 18.04, icons

I changed the icon of a `.sh` file i have using `gio set -t 'string' folderIWishToInsertIcon 'metadata::custom-icon' 'file:///home/myUser/myIcon.png'`. However, i am trying to find a way to keep this icon on the file if i sent this file to another user to use. Is there a way to lock the icon on the file? Or maybe another way to change the icon on my file without it reverting back to its original icon when it's sent to another user?
Thank you in advance!

**Update:**

As stated below in the answers, `gio set` is a needs user configuration to change the icon of the file, so we will not be able to lock the icon if used by another user. So my question is updated to: Does anyone know a way to change the icon of a python script  that doesn't require user configuration (so that the icon changed still shows for other users)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The reason is that, by design, the icon by which a file is displayed in a file manager, is determined by the configuration of the user, thus by the user. That icon may be different on a user account on the same machine, and it will very likely be different for  a user account using a different desktop, on a user account on another computer, and most certainly on a computer running another operating system.

The `gio` command sets a user configuration under your account. You would need to supply the icon and configure each account, in as far if that account uses the same configuration system (e.g. a desktop like KDE will not).

Comment: Thank you so much! your answer was very insightful! However do u know any other way to change the icon of a folder or a python script to be specific without user configuration?

Comment: My answer indicated that that will be difficult due to the fundamental design of how these icons are implemented.

Comment: Yes i understand your answer very well! However, i am sure their is a way to change the icons without user configuration and i think it is done maybe through a python code or something including executing a python script, so i will try my best to find it and continue my research! Thank you for your help

Comment: Icons *are* user configuration, so I am not sure how you can be sure there is a way to change icons without user configuration. Good luck, though. Do not hesitate to post an answer here yourself if you find the solution elsewhere: this is perfectly acceptable - and advised - on this site.